# Gratis Windows File Rename utility

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, rename

DropBox has messed me up :-(

Suddenly, a lot of my `file.extension` files have been renamed as `file (Mawg's Laptop's conflicted copy 2020-01-15).extension` and replaced by ***older*** versions (?!).

I need a gratis Windows File Rename utility which will recurse a directory tree & rename all `file (Mawg's Laptop's conflicted copy 2020-01-15).extension` to `file.extension`, overwriting those older files.

I have tried :

- A.F.5 Rename your files
- Ant file renamer
- File Renamer - Basic
- Flexible Renamer

none of which appear to help.

Does anyone know of a gratis Windows File Rename utility which can do that? Something ***that you use*** - not just something googled for, please.

Comment: Sounds like a job for your own custom script (I'd use Python, but I'm sure there are plenty of decent options for this; maybe PowerShell?). Especially the deletion of the files that currently have the name you want; I wouldn't expect any ready-made utility to have that. But good luck! Your requirements are fairly special, I think, so if people follow your directive to only offer what they've used, I think this has a good chance of being a self-answered question. ;)

Comment: Be careful. Conflicts are there to be solved by humans manually. At least in Git, SVN and other version control systems. You might lose data by simply overwriting other files.

Comment: Besides writing a custom script, my first thought (I suppose, second, actually) was to use FreeCommander XE (https://freecommander.com/). It has an *amazing* file search tool integrated into it as well as an extraordinarily *flexible* mult-rename tool. It also has the ability to *flatten all subfolders* into a single list.  Finally, you can *filter* all of the output using flexible filters.  I think with a little work and cleverness, you might be able to use it to do exactly what you want.  It runs on Windows, has a portable version, and is gratis, with donations welcomed by the author, Marek.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - That's probably enough information to make it a full-fledged answer! Throw in a screenshot and it's as legitimate an answer as anything else.

Comment: @JohnY Hi John! Thanks for your confidence! You aren't able to see it, but I actually wrote the beginning of an answer, and then chose to delete it once I realized that I wasn't 99% sure it would work (you can't really be 100% sure of anything!).  But if anyone tries it and determines it's a good answer, I'm happy to write it up.

Comment: @JohnY BTW, you can upvote individual comments that you find helpful to help prevent them from getting hidden when StackExchange automatically shortens the page in some situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at **Bulk Rename Utility** which seems to be able to do the job.

Free download (also portable version available): https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

1. In **Renaming Options** > **Advenced Options** select ***Allow Overwrite*** and agree to the warning
2. Make sure ***Subfolders*** is checked
3. Add the main folder, and select all files
4. Put the string (with the leading space) in the ***Replace*** field
5. **Rename!**

[image]

Comment: I though that I was doing it wrongly! Upvate, and the answer when you explain further. What I tried was 1) select directory, 2) include sub-directories 3) "`string replacement`, replacing the string with empty string 4) on the previous tab to that one, Ctrl+A 5) "Go". That did not work, can you please give step by step instructions? Thanks!

Comment: Does it also delete/overwrite existing files?

Comment: @YisroelTech I would accept this answer if you would update it to show how to do it. I notice that  you chose the "character deletion option" and it actually says on your screenshot "To delete a specified string, use the String Replacement action and replace the string with an empty one" - which is what I was trying to do. Can you explain how, please? Thanks

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica, I used **Character deletion** instead of **String replacement** because I don't understand from your question exactly if all the files have the same date in this added string. So I just deleted the last 45 characters.

Comment: But indeed I totally missed the File Replace part which **Ant Renamer** can totally NOT do. Changing my answer to something else...

Comment: Completely changing your answer to something else isn't how this is supposed to work. If you no longer feel an answer applies to the question, then delete the answer. If you want to recommend a different software package, then create a new answer for it. It is perfectly fine to have multiple answers from the same person, one answer for each software package being recommended. That is actually the ideal situation, since the votes can then be applied more precisely.

Comment: As it stands, almost all the comments to this answer make no sense anymore, and there was at least one vote for Ant Renamer before you changed it to BRU.

Answer (score 2):

## [Advanced File Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/)

There is no type of renaming that this program cannot do (among other things). It supports anything from layman-friendly patterns, to regular expressions, to full on scripting (hence the "can do everything"). It also has a CLI, for the really advanced uses.

It will show you the results before renaming your files, so you don't make any mistakes.
It can also deal with file metadata (e.g. from music or image files) and use it in the naming.

And it's **free for personal use** (only commercial use requires license).

There is also a **portable version** - you can check it out without having to install anything.

[image]

Comment: Does it allow you to delete/overwrite existing files? According to [this documentation](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/name_collision_rules) it seems like it doesn't. But it might do something almost as good, which is to rename upon collision. My question is: If you start out with `fileA` and `fileB` and you then rename `fileA` as `fileB`, which file gets the extra numbers at the end? If it's guaranteed that the original `fileB` will be renamed to `fileB_001` and the original `fileA` will be renamed to `fileB`, then I think this is close enough to meeting the stated requirements.

Comment: Well, I mean it doesn't overwrite, but it can move files. So you can do it in 2 operations - move all the bad files away, then rename all the good files. 1. Add all the non-matching files and move them away to wherever; 2. Add all the matching files and remove the pattern. (The only real shortcoming I found is, it can't preserve folder structure when using `Output folder` without scripting.)

Comment: But there is no simple way to select "the bad files". Their names do not follow any pattern. The only way to recognize those files (let alone move them) is to first identify the good files that we want to rename (whose names **do** follow a pattern) and rename them, at least tentatively. The good files are scattered around in arbitrary folders, so I am not confident there is an easy way to move *them* away, then rename them, then move them back (but if there were, then the "move them back" step could leverage the operating system's own overwrite-on-copy feature).

Comment: @JohnY **Yes, there is**, you just invert the selector. When you add files, you can add all files that **DON'T** match your pattern. You don't get any more simple than a checkbox.

Comment: @JohnY Just download the thing, it has a portable version. That way you don't have to speculate in the comments and mislead people with your statements of surety.

Comment: You miss my point. You cannot invert the selector because that will capture some files that should not be captured. If you read OP's situation, they said **some** of their files got that crazy, unwanted rename/restore. So before the mishap, there were (for example) `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`. But after the mishap, there were `foo_with_extra_pattern.txt` (which is the good one), `foo.txt` (which is an old, unwanted one), and `bar.txt` (which is unchanged and still good). If you simply invert the selector, you will get one good file and one bad file.

Comment: Ah, so I do. Then you're off writing your own script. This program's scripting is JavaScript based, or one can use any other preferred standalone scripting language(e.g. python).